# Intersection of lines from lineair systems defines a conic section

Tags: conic-sections, projective-geometry

I have two pencils of hyperplanes $\Sigma_1$ and $\Sigma_2$ in $P^2(\mathbb{R})$ and a projective map $\phi \colon \Sigma_1 \to \Sigma_2$. Now I need to show that the the points that are defined by $l_1 \cap \phi(l_1)$, with $l_1 \in \Sigma_1$ forms a conic section in $P^2(\mathbb{R})$.

I first thought that I could show it by using the eigenvectors of the matrix associated with the projective map but any point on the line $l_1$ could map to itself so now I have no idea how I can prove this.

Comment: What is a "lineair system of hyperplanes"?  Do you mean a pencil of hyperplanes?

Comment: See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steiner_conic.

Comment: Yeah I mean a pencil of hyperplanes! This is a question that was originally in Dutch and I didn’t find a translation but now I know!